# Embedding and existentially quantified formula

Tags: logic, model-theory

I wanted to prove that given an existentially quantified formula $\varphi(\bar{y})=\exists\bar{x}\psi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ and an embedding $f : \mathfrak{M} \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{N}$ between two $\mathscr{L}$-structures $\mathfrak{M}$ and $\mathfrak{N}$, there is for any $\bar{a} \in M^k$,
$$\mathfrak{M} \models \varphi(\bar{a}) \Rightarrow \mathfrak{N} \models \varphi(f(\bar{a})). \tag{*}$$

(*$f(\bar{a})$ denotes $f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n)$*).

I already proven that given a quantifier-free formula $\psi$,  $$\mathfrak{M} \models \psi(\bar{a}) \iff \mathfrak{N} \models \varphi(f(\bar{a})) \tag{**}.$$ I have a wrong proof for (*) but wasn't able to figure out wherever was erroneous:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{M} \models \exists \bar{x} \psi(\bar{x}, \bar{a}) &\iff \textrm{exists $\bar{b} \in M^k$, s.t. $\mathfrak{M} \models \psi(\bar{b}, \bar{a})$} \tag{Definition}\\
&\iff \textrm{exists $f(\bar{b}) \in N^k$, s.t. }\mathfrak{N} \models \psi(f(\bar{b}), f(\bar{a})) \tag{**}\\
& \iff \mathfrak{N} \models \exists\bar{x} \psi(\bar{x}, f(\bar{a})) \tag{Definition}
\end{align*}
$$

I'm not sure which logical equivalence is wrong.

Comment: At the risk of embarrassing myself, are you sure your proof is incorrect? The only thing that stands out to me is that you should only have $\Rightarrow$ rather than a $\Leftrightarrow$ when going from line 2 to 3. That is, $(**)$ implies the conclusion, but the conclusion does NOT in general imply $(**)$. Of course, from your question it seems you only _want_ to prove $\Rightarrow$, so this is not a big issue.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Your comment is exactly right and you do point out the mistake in OP's proof. You should post this as an answer!

Comment: Thank you for the replies, however that is exactly the part where I'm unsure about: I know that something goes wrong but unable to say why. The definition says that $\mathfrak{M}\models \exists x \varphi(x) \iff $ it exists $a \in M$ s.t. $\mathfrak{M} \models \varphi(a)$, I can't see why the converse $\Leftarrow$ is not true (_i.e._ frome line 3 to line 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's show that the converse $$\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi(f(\overline{a}))\quad\implies\quad\mathfrak{M}\models\varphi(\overline{a})$$ is **false** in general; this will help uncover the issue with your proof.

Working in the empty language for simplicity, let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a one-element structure and let $\mathfrak{N}$ be a two-element structure. Let $a$ be the unique element of $\mathfrak{M}$ and fix some $f:\mathfrak{M}\rightarrow\mathfrak{N}$; note that **any** such $f$ is an embedding. Then we have $$\mathfrak{N}\models\exists x(x\not=f(a))\quad\mbox{but}\quad \mathfrak{M}\models\neg\exists x(x\not=a).$$ So $\exists$-sentences are only "upwards absolute" in general.

---

OK, so based on this where is the issue in your argument?

Well, the problem above was that the witness to the existential statement holding in $\mathfrak{N}$ was not itself in the image of $f$, so it couldn't be "pulled down" to a witness in $\mathfrak{M}$. This shows us the problem in reversing the final implication:

> We do have $$\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi(f(\overline{a}))\quad\implies\quad \exists \overline{c}\in\mathfrak{N}\mbox{ such that }\mathfrak{N}\models\psi(\overline{c},f(\overline{a})),$$ but we cannot assume that there is $\overline{b}\in\mathfrak{M}$ such that $f(\overline{b})=\overline{c}$. So we do **not** have $$\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi(f(\overline{a}))\quad\implies\quad \exists \overline{b}\in\mathfrak{M}\mbox{ such that }\mathfrak{N}\models\psi(f(\overline{b}),f(\overline{a}))$$ in general.

Comment: Thank you, Noah, the counterexample is concise, pedagogic, and convincing.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm not sure I have followed the second part:
I understood that $\mathfrak{N} \models \varphi(f(\bar{a})) \implies \exists \bar{b} \in \mathfrak{M}$, such that $\mathfrak{N} \models \psi(f(\bar{b}), f(\bar{a}))$ is
not true in general, but I still wonder
 why we can't say  $\mathfrak{N} \models \varphi(f(\bar{a})) \implies \exists
\bar{c} \in \mathfrak{N}$ _which happens to be $f(\bar{b})$_ such that
$\mathfrak{N} \models \psi(\bar{c}, f(\bar{a}))$. What is the nuance between
this statement and the first one you gave which holds ?

Comment: @user428953 Why *should* that $\overline{c}$ have the form $f(\overline{b})$ for some $\overline{b}\in\mathfrak{M}$? It might, but it might not - and if in a step in your argument you need this to be the case, you need to justify it rather than just assume it tacitly. And my example shows exactly that this doesn't always happen.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, in proof-theoretic terms, I guess I had simply reversed the $\exists{\rm intro}$ rule in some classical proof calculus without thinking too much.